# Is there a way to append user input to an array in Scala without overriding my old input every time I call the function?

Tags: arrays, scala, append

I am trying to build a todo list in Scala and I am having trouble with my addItem function.  I want it to be able to create an array of strings that stores the user's input but with what I have now, the user input is getting overridden each time instead of saving the old input.

```
def addItem() = {

    val input = scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
    var list = Array[String](input) :+ input
    list.foreach(println)
}
```

I expect this code to print each user input that has been entered since the compilation, but instead, it just prints the most recent input 2 times.

I made this menu and main function that calls the function I wish to use.

```
def menu(option: Int): Boolean = {
  option match {
    case 1 =>
      addItem()
      true
    case 2 =>
      println("Enter item to delete")
      true
    case 3 =>
      println("Here is your todo list")
      false
    case 4 =>
      println("selected quit")
      false
    case _ => // the else case
      println("Unrecognized command")
      true
  }
}
}
```

every time I push the number 1, I want to be able to add an item to the list and have that item be stored with the previously added ones.  I can't figure out how to store more than one value with what I have so far.  My goal is to be able to add an item to be stored each time without overriding the previously stored item.

I should push 1, be prompted to add an item, I then enter the item and it should be stored.  If I push 1 again, I should again be prompted to add another item, so when I print it after the two inputs, both items should print.

Comment: Your expectation is wrong. `Array(input)` creates an array with only one member (*input*). then `:+` appends *input* to it again. So you end up with an array that has the same string twice.

Comment: You can simply do a `input.split(" ")` to get an array with all  user input as elements assuming it is separated with whitespaces.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but every time I call the function, I want the user to be able to add another item that will be stored.  I am now having the problem with the first user input getting overridden each time I call the function and add a new item, does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code that you use to call this function. A toy test case with given inputs and expected outputs can go a long way. If you need more details, take a look at [mre]

Answer (score 1):

The list that you are using to "store" your input is within `addItem` function, which is not correct. You should move `list` outside, initialize as empty and then append the new input within the function `addItem`.
With your current implementation, you are using `list` in a local way, and each time that you call `addItem` will create a new `list`.

Additionally, in your code:

```
var list = Array[String](input) :+ input
```

You're assigning an array initialized with only one item (`input`) and then, you're appending again `input` to that new array.

Comment: I tried doing what you said and it worked.  I am now getting an output that looks like this: MutableList(go to school, eat dinner, do homework)...etc.  do you have any advice on how I can get it to print to look more like a list?  ordering from top to bottom instead of side to side?

Comment: You can try:  `yourOutput.toList.foreach(println)`

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a simple recursive function to aggregate the Array of to-do items, as shown below:

```
def inputToDo(quit: String): Array[String] = {
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def loop(acc: Array[String]): Array[String] =
    scala.io.StdIn.readLine match {
      case x if x == quit => acc
      case x => loop(acc :+ x)
    }
  loop(Array.empty[String])
}

val toDoList = inputToDo("q")
// grocery
// laundry
// q
// toDoList: Array[String] = Array(grocery, laundry)
```

Comment: Isn't it better to use `List` here instead of `Array`? `:+` copies the whole array before appending a new element.

Comment: @jrook, yeah, would've used `List` if `Array` isn't what OP seems to want as the resulting collection. And this is for manual input of a handful of to-do items, hence I didn't make performance a priority.